# Z-Index using element positioned relatively to overlap image

Tags: css, z-index, css-position

site: forus-group.com

I am trying to position the right navigation to overlap the sliding header images. No matter how high of a z-index I give it, it will not overlap the images, who's parent sections have a z-index of 3. Both elements are, of coarse, positioned relatively to facilitate z-index.

Even when I try to give the images themselves a negative z-index, they still overlap the right column. Relevant CSS is below:

```
#right {
     width: 275px;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 175px;
     z-index: 50;
}

#tophead .cycleitem img {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;    
}
```

All other items (in the header) display correctly when given a z-index of 50. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** Site now reverted to broken state. Bug came up when trying to fix IE 7 and lower but now appears in modern brosers. I have the header at full height, with the content below. I then try to position the right column relatively with:

```
position: relative;
bottom: 175px;
z-index: 150;
```

Thanks again.

Comment: My I please ask what browser are you using? I know some older IE browsers doesnot suport z-index. [Read](http://systembash.com/content/css-z-index-internet-explorer/)

Comment: IE supports z-index, it's just broken.

Comment: Not all IE's I know IE 6 and 7 have some problems with z-index. [READ HERE](http://systembash.com/content/css-z-index-internet-explorer/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the menu is actually in a different document section than the header:

```
<header id="tophead">
    header image here
</head>
<section id="content">
    sidebar menu here
</section>
```

If you want the menu to overlap the header image, you'll have to restructure the document. One hack-ish method would be to make the sidebar's `top: -313px`, which matches the header's height.

Comment: According to document flow, the content is _currently_ below the header, with the #right section positioned relatively to float upwards over-top of the header. It just appears behind.